# Validate File Path on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to validate a directory path before proceeding with downstream code.
I have tried using TRY/CATCH with the code below, but it returns error code 3, which escapes TRY/CATCH.
In T-SQL, how would one validate a file path?

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_subdirs 'C:\Invalid Path'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 'Invalid Destination Location'
END CATCH
```

Comment: What is the error message and severity? It's probably a fatal error which is closing the connection. Suffice to say that `xp_` procedures should be avoided. SQL is not the place to muck around with files, use batch or Powershell for that.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative mechanism is to use XP_FileExists undocumented stored procedure, note just like XP_SubDirs this system stored procedure may not exist in future versions of SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (FileExists int, IsDirectory int, ParentDirExists int)

INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC master..xp_fileexist 'C:\Invalid Path'

IF EXISTS(SELECT IsDirectory FROM #Temp WHERE IsDirectory = 1)
    PRINT 'Folder Exists'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Folder Doesnt Exists'
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some exceptions to what SQL Server's TRY/CATCH will actually catch.  Read towards the bottom of the reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
In your case, I believe your error is a severity level below 10, so will not be "caught"

The relevant section from SQL Server docs:

> **Errors Unaffected by a TRY...CATCH Construct TRY...CATCH constructs do not trap the following conditions:**
>
> Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or
> lower.
>
> Errors that have a severity of 20 or higher that stop the SQL Server
> Database Engine task processing for the session. If an error occurs
> that has severity of 20 or higher and the database connection is not
> disrupted, TRY...CATCH will handle the error.
>
> Attentions, such as client-interrupt requests or broken client
> connections.
>
> When the session is ended by a system administrator by using the KILL
> statement.
>
> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
> they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY...CATCH
> construct:
>
> Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
> running.
>
> Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object
> name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of
> deferred name resolution.
>
> Object name resolution errors
>
> These errors are returned to the level that ran the batch, stored
> procedure, or trigger.
>
> If an error occurs during compilation or statement-level recompilation
> at a lower execution level (for example, when executing sp_executesql
> or a user-defined stored procedure) inside the TRY block, the error
> occurs at a lower level than the TRY...CATCH construct and will be
> handled by the associated CATCH block.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK.  First question I've answered where the need to incorporate a section from a link is relevant.  Is there a particular way that I should format it?

Answer (score 0):

The error does not originate from SQL Server in this case and can't be caught in this manner.

A possible work-around is to check the path exists, at least for current versions of SQL Server:

```
declare @Exists table (Exist int, IsDirectory int, HasParent int) 

insert into @Exists exec master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'c:\invalid'
if exists (select * from @Exists where exist=1 and isdirectory=1)
begin
    select 'Folder exists'
end
else
begin
    select 'Invalid folder'
end
```